# Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost [Started,Synchronized] but the eclipse browser is not opening

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat, localhost

1. I have installed Eclipse **Oxygen** ( Version: Oxygen Release Milestone 6
   (4.7.0 M6))
2. I have installed Apache Tomcat v9.0 .
3. I have installed java jdk and jre1.8.0_131 and have set classpath.

First I installed **JST Adapters and Extensions** then I was able to add Apache Tomcat server.

The server says started synchronized but doesn't open Eclipse browser.[image]

When I again click on the green run button it says the following:

> Several ports (8005, 8080, 8009) required by Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).

My Tomcat server is running as shown:
[image]

I added Apache Tomcat v9.0 by **Window->Preferences->Server->Runtime Environments** then clicked on **Add** then selected **Apache Tomcat v9.0** then clicked **Next** then browsed the path to **C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0** and selected **jre1.8.0_131** then clicked on **finish**[image]

I also tried to change port numbers previously but it didn't help.
Then following an answer on stackoverflow I did the following :
i clicked on **Window->Show View->Other->Server->Servers** then clicked **OK**
Then **servers** Tab appeared .I opened **Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost** .
Then I opened **Open launch configuration** ,then selected **tomcat-juli.jar** from Tomcat's **bin** folder and clicked **OK**.
[image]

When I run server this appears in console tab:

```
May 15, 2017 2:51:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M21
May 15, 2017 2:51:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          May 4 2017 22:42:36 UTC
May 15, 2017 2:51:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         9.0.0.0
May 15, 2017 2:51:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
May 15, 2017 2:51:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
May 15, 2017 2:51:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
May 15, 2017 2:51:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131
May 15, 2017 2:51:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_131-b11
May 15, 2017 2:51:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
May 15, 2017 2:51:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\aakri\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
May 15, 2017 2:51:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
May 15, 2017 2:51:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\aakri\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
May 15, 2017 2:51:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
May 15, 2017 2:51:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\aakri\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
May 15, 2017 2:51:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\endorsed
May 15, 2017 2:51:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
May 15, 2017 2:51:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_131/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_131/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_131/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\eclipse;;.]
May 15, 2017 2:51:05 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
May 15, 2017 2:51:05 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
May 15, 2017 2:51:05 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
May 15, 2017 2:51:05 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
May 15, 2017 2:51:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1339 ms
May 15, 2017 2:51:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
May 15, 2017 2:51:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M21
May 15, 2017 2:51:06 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
May 15, 2017 2:51:06 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
May 15, 2017 2:51:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 951 ms
```

edit:
i tried to reach http://localhost:8080/UserHome:[image]

edit 2:I could not **deploy assembly** of the **jar files** and **servlet api** using the above mentioned versions of eclipse so I changed eclipse current version to Version: **Oxygen Release Milestone 5 (4.7.0 M5)** also i changed the tomcat v9 to **v8.5**.**Then successfully assembly was deployed and now both are running fine.**

Comment: Can you see anything in console log when the server starts up?

Comment: @DarshanMehta I have included it in the question now.

Comment: Looks like it's starting up without any error. Can you see anything in error log or catalina log when you try to access the url?

Comment: Let's try to access your web via URL, in image above you are accessing to `localhost:8080` it is the home page of tomcat, and this home page can unavailable

Comment: this may be a painful suggestion but have you tried using tomcat v8.5 instead as tomcat v9 is currently in it's alpha stages?

Comment: @Bill F I changed versions of both now they are running fine because i was not able to deploy assembly in previously specified version of eclipse.

Comment: @TuyenNguyen i included the screenshot in the first edit .